# How to concat php and html code?

Tags: php, html

```
<table  border="3" style= "background-color: white ; color: black; margin: 0 auto;" >
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ItemName</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <?php foreach($complaintsObj as $data){
            if($data['itemStatus'] == 1){
    echo "<tr>
             <td>{$data['itemName']}</td>
             <td>{$data['masterServiceAmount']}</td>
          </tr>\n";
                }
                    }
        echo
         "<tr>
            <td>TOTAL AMOUNT</td>
            <td>{$originalAmount}</td>                                       
          </tr>\n";
            ?>
    </tbody>
```

As how to concat above code as putting html code in a variable and it can be used again in the program as any one have any idea how to do it?

Comment: `$variable = "<b>Put in whatever you want</b><br>";`

Comment: Learn about templates and available engines (even Smarty)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the variable, and then build it up piece by piece:

```
$sOutput = <<<TABLE_HEAD
    <table  border="3" style= "background-color: white ; color: black; margin: 0 auto;" >
                                                    <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <th>ItemName</th>
                                                    <th>Amount</th>
                                                     </tr>
                                                     </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
TABLE_HEAD;   //This is a constuct called a "Here document". Necessary, because you are building a multiline string with quotes.
<?php

    foreach($complaintsObj as $data){

        if($data['itemStatus'] == 1){

            $sOutput .=
                "<tr>
                <td>{$data['itemName']}</td>
                <td>{$data['masterServiceAmount']}</td>
                </tr>\n";

        }
    }
    $sOutput .=
        "<tr>
        <td>TOTAL AMOUNT</td>
        <td>{$originalAmount}</td>

        </tr>\n";
?>
$sOutput .= "</tbody>
          </table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it's a bad practice to do this, but I'll show you the way.

You just have to put your HTML in a PHP var, like this :

```
<?php $my_var = '<div>john<strong>doe</strong></div>'; ?>
```

Then, you can print the HTML this way :

```
<?php echo $my_var; ?>
```

Here is the proper way : using [include()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.include.php).
Just create another PHP file containing your HTML.
Then, you just have to call this function to retrieve your HTML everywhere you want :

```
<?php include('my_html.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

For such small code the best you can use is not

```
<?php $myv_var = '<div>john<strong>doe</strong></div>'; ?>
```

or,

```
<?php include('my_html.php'); ?>
```

Since you are using a `foreach` loop I recommend you to use this:

```
<?php foreach($complaintsObj as $data) { if($data['itemStatus'] == 1) { ?>
<tr>
<td>{$data['itemName']}</td>
<td>{$data['masterServiceAmount']}</td>
</tr>\n
<?php } } ?>
<?php echo "<tr><td>TOTAL AMOUNT</td><td>{$originalAmount}</td></tr>\n"; ?>
```

But if you really want to use the same HTML in other code then

```
<?php include('my_html.php'); ?>
```

Is your best option